# How to use the phrase "cash advance"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Suppose I want to withdraw money from a card through a cashier in a bank via cash advance and to deposit the money to another card. What's the most natural way to ask for this? I think "can I withdraw $800 from this card via cash advance and deposit it to this card?" sounds unnatural.

Comment: Maybe this is more for Money.SE, but a *balance transfer* combines the withdrawal and deposit into one step, and sometimes is more advantageous in terms of fees and interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want a cash advance of $800 on card X, and then to deposit the money to card Y.

X and Y should identify the specific cards, perhaps by brand, or last-4-digits.

The "via" can be omitted, and so can "withdraw", as a cash advance is assumed to be withdrawn unless one specifically mentions repaying it or making a payment or deposit. (Unless it is to a debit card or a secured credit card -- a card backed by a savings account-- one usually speaks of a payment, not a deposit.)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say: I'd like to take out a cash advance of $800 from my card xxxx (take out an $800 cash advance on my card xxxx) and deposit that money to my card yyyy.